# Drupal Services session authentication not working with Angular 2 (Error 406: user is not logged in)

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular, drupal-7, drupal-services

I have front-end with Angular and its connected to drupal backend. I am using drupal services module for rest api.

Issue is when I logg in using rest , I can get all session details like session_name , sessid and token.

In Angular , for all further request I send header as below :-

```
{
‘X-CSRF-Token’: thetoken,
‘Cookie’: formedcookie
}
```

But , it always return **Error 406 : user is not logged in.** Even when I try logging out.

When trying in **POSTMAN rest client** , everything works. Only , In angular it doesn't work.

EDIT :- Its been two days am trying this , and still not working. Maybe , session authentication doesn't work with angular apps ? tried http basic auth , that too didn't work. Is it about way , the headers are supposed to be sent ?

Comment: Please try the below reference: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213948/login-users-sessions-persistence-using-services-and-rest-server-modules/213997